# Should I season my sushi rice before or after cooking?

Tags: rice, seasoning, sushi, timing

When I make rice for sushi, I season it with sugar, salt, rice vinegar, and mirin. I'm never sure if I should add these at the beginning or near the end of cooking the rice. Does it matter when I add these seasonings?

Answer (score 5):

You should add the seasoning at the end of cooking the rice.

Actually normally I let my rice cool down for 10-15 minutes and transfer it to a large mixing bowl before mixing the seasoning with my rice.

I do not think it matters when you add the salt BUT the wet ingredients (including sugar) should be added after the water has been absorbed by the rice.

Comment: Why would sugar be considered a wet ingredient in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

You should drizzle your rice vinegar/sugar/salt/mirin reduction a little at a time while the rice is spread to cool. Drizzle a little, then fold. Repeat until your reduction is gone and continue to let your rice cool until ready to use.

Don't try to store leftover rice. It's a petri dish for bacteria that cause food poisoning.